# Why aren't two systems considered as one instead of saying we are doing no work on one of them?

Tags: work

Suppose i have on my head a block that is applying its force (weight) perpendicularly on my head. now suddenly i start moving with the block still on my head.

According to the definition of work , I am doing no work on the block. But as the block has increased my mass , i am using more force to accelerate myself to the same speed , that i would have had gained without the block on my head.In other words the block and i are a unifies system now and i am doing work on the block part of my system to accelerate it.

please correct me , because i feel i have somehow made a mistake in thinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> According to the definition of work , I am doing no work on the block.

That's not true at all. You're exerting a force on the block as it moves through some distance, so you're doing work on it.

Comment: now i realise that how weird my question was . Should i delete the question?

Comment: That's up to you

Comment: well , lets leave it there . Maybe there may be someone else in this world who is as foolish as me !